# Here Maps cors problem - only local resources (no external resources)

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

We are working on a customer project that would require that
no resources are loaded from external resources (strict corse policy).
Is there a way to use here maps with local resources only?

Comment: I am not sure if you work for mobile platforms. But with the HERE SDK (Navigate Edition) you can download whole countries or continents. With offline maps, https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.7.2.0/dev_guide/topics/offline-maps.html, you can fully work offline. Once the map data is downloaded, the device can operate in flight mode to search, route or even navigate on the map to destinations - fully offline without any connection - and therefore without loading external resources.

Answer (score 0):

The HERE SDK for iOS (Premium Edition) would support offline maps:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/3.18/dev_guide/topics/use-cases.html

Of course there is also an Android version:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.18/dev_guide/topics/use-cases.html